# Push Notification icon turns white in Android lollipop and above

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I having trouble to send notification to device SDK >= 21.
The notification icon is blank.

What I tried so far:

1. Changing android target sdk to 20
2. I checked the if statement for lollipop devices:

   ```
   if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
   ```
3. I have set my drawable icon to 72*72 and placed the drawable twice in drawable and drawable-v21 folder

I tried all above and still the notification is showing as blank.

I tried more search I got adding a silhouette icon to the app and use it if the device is running Android Lollipop.

Any suggestions? This is my FirebaseMessagingService class:

```
public class myFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
Bitmap bitmap;

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    //
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
    //You can change as per the requirement.
    //message will contain the Push Message
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.
    String TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");

    //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

    sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);

}


/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 */

private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ahed_icon)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

}

/*
*To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
* */
public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}


private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ahed_icon)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

This is my drawable I want to show in the notification:

[image: notification_icon]

Any further information I am ready to provide it.

Comment: I had the same problem. When I push notifications from firebase, on some devices it worked on some it showed up as blank. I will try what you have tried and keep you posted if I find something useful.

Comment: @koksalb good try it and tell me

Answer (score 1):

Use largeIcon for lollipop and above devices, It will work like charm

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ahed_icon)
    .setLargeIcon(bitmapImage)
    .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
    .setContentText(messageBody)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: same not working !! if it s really working there we make a contact so we could fix it on my side

Comment: May I have your latest Notification code after setting largeIcon?

Comment: just i added it in in first send notification method who s having three parameters..
I think the code have something wrong can u please pass your own

Comment: Is your android studio's instant run is enabled?If yes than Clean your project, rebuild it and run again. sometimes it doesn't work and after rebuilding project it works.

Comment: same result can u really help me so we could fix it on my side